java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Exception cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
Currently, I am creating a library that will be responsible for handling exceptions in a project. This library is already being imported into the main project, and has a GlobalExceptionHandler in addition to several custom error types defined.
In a certain part of the code I have:
@Slf4j
@RestControllerAdvice
public class  GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Resource
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleGeneral(Exception e, WebRequest request) {
        String message = "";
        if (e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UndeclaredThrowableException.class)) {

I am managing to throw an Exception and it is being caught by the global handler, however when it reaches this IF
e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UndeclaredThrowableException.class), it is giving the following error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Exception cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException (java.lang.Exception and java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Can anyone help me? This piece of code works correctly when exception handling is done directly in the project. I have no idea how to proceed.
Note: e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UndeclaredThrowableException.class) == true, according to the intellij debugger, but from what I've been researching, isAssignableFrom tries to perform a cast and then the error appears.
I've already tried debugging a project and researching this error in other situations but I didn't find anything that helped me.
--- New informations
The code belongs to my company, so I don't know how far I can share it.
It's code that was already being used and working, my task was exclusively to take this part of the exceptions, create a new lib and import it into the original project. Therefore, all exceptions, the globalexceptionhandler and types are in the lib, and it is being imported as follows:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test_lib_errorcodes</artifactId>
    <version>${test-lib-errorcodes.version}</version>
</dependency>

The code below is very similar to the code in the project:
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Resource
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    private HttpHeaders headers(){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return headers;
    }
    private ResponseError responseError(String message,HttpStatus statusCode){
        ResponseError responseError = new ResponseError();
        responseError.setStatus("error");
        responseError.setError(message);
        responseError.setStatusCode(statusCode.value());
        return responseError;
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleGeneral(Exception e, WebRequest request) {
        if (e.getClass().isAssignableFrom(UndeclaredThrowableException.class)) {
            UndeclaredThrowableException exception = (UndeclaredThrowableException) e;
            return handleBusinessException((BusinessException) exception.getUndeclaredThrowable(), request);
        } else {
            String message = messageSource.getMessage("error.server", new Object[]{e.getMessage()}, null);
            ResponseError error = responseError(message,HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return handleExceptionInternal(e, error, headers(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
        }
    }
    @ExceptionHandler({BusinessException.class})
    private ResponseEntity<Object> handleBusinessException(BusinessException e, WebRequest request) {
        ResponseError error = responseError(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        return handleExceptionInternal(e, error, headers(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
}


What is you runtime environment? Plain Spring Boot Application or some application server like WebLogic or Tomcat? How do you "import" the library info the project? Please, provide the full stacktrace!

Your code is incomplete. From what you’ve posted, we can only assume that you are performing a type cast from e to UndeclaredThrowableException within the if statement, when the condition is true. The method isAssignableFrom itself does not perform a type cast at all.
In that case, you have it backwards. To test whether e can be assigned to a variable of type UndeclaredThrowableException, you have to use
if(UndeclaredThrowableException.class.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())) {
    UndeclaredThrowableException u = (UndeclaredThrowableException)e;
    …
}

As you are assigning u from e. But this is  unnecessarily complicated. Just write
if(e instanceof UndeclaredThrowableException) {
    UndeclaredThrowableException u = (UndeclaredThrowableException)e;
    …
}

and then it’s impossible to mix up the arguments.
Since Java 16, you can simplify it further
if(e instanceof UndeclaredThrowableException u) {
    // use u
    …
}

not even having a type cast that could fail.
